# Scodec: Using vectorOfN with a vlong field

Tags: scala, scodec

I am playing around with the Bitcoin blockchain to learn Scala and some useful libraries.
Currently I am trying to decode and encode Blocks with SCodec and my problem is that the vectorOfN function takes its size as an Int. How can I use a long field for the size while still **preserving the full value range**.
In other words is there a vectorOfLongN function?

This is my code which would compile fine if I were using vintL instead of vlongL:

```
object Block {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Block] = {
    ("header" | Codec[BlockHeader]) ::
    (("numTx" | vlongL) >>:~
      { numTx => ("transactions" | vectorOfN(provide(numTx), Codec[Transaction]) ).hlist })
  }.as[Block]
}
```

You may assume that appropriate Codecs for the Blockheader and the Transactions are implemented. Actually, vlong is used as a simplification for this question, because Bitcoin uses its own codec for variable sized ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a scodec specialist but my common sense suggests that this is not possible because Scala's `Vector` being a subtype of `GenSeqLike` is limited to have `length` of type `Int` and `apply` that accepts `Int` index as its argument. And AFAIU this limitation comes from the underlying JVM platform where you can't have an array of size more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` i.e. around 2^31 (see also ["Criticism of Java" wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays)). And although `Vector` theoretically could have work this limitation around, it was not done. So it makes no sense for `vectorOfN` to support `Long` size as well.

In other words, if you want something like this, you probably should start from creating your own Vector-like class that does support `Long` indices working around JVM limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [scodec-stream](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-stream), which comes in handy when all of your data is not available immediately or does not fit into memory.

Basically, you would use your usual `codecs.X` and turn it into a `StreamDecoder` via `scodec.stream.decode.many(normal_codec)`. This way you can work with the data through `scodec` without the need to load it into memory entirely.

A `StreamDecoder` then offers methods like `decodeInputStream` along `scodec's` usual `decode`.

(I used it a while ago in a slightly different context – parsing data sent by a client to a server – but it looks like it would apply here as well).